# Return php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have made a little AJAX-script for my site, which executes a php-script in another file on submission. I managed to echo out the result in the original file with the AJAX-function, but I have not managed to transfer a variable from the php file to the original one.

I need this variable in order to add an event listener which will look for changes in that particular variable (not sure how to do that either).

Comment: By the time you make the ajax call to hej.php, `$show` has already been declared and interpreted on `forsok.php`, and it is already too late. Maybe if you showed us how you plan on using `$show`, we could figure out what you really need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's are what you are looking for it's working:- 
Put this in your forsok.php

```
<div id="input">
<input type="text" id="number" name="value">
<b id="show_result"></b>
</div>`
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$('#number').on('keyup',function(e){
if(e.which == 13){
var get_var_name = $(this).val();
 $.get('result.php',{number:get_var_name},function(data,status){
if(status == 'success'){
 alert(data['show']);
 $('#show_result').text(data['show']);
}else{
 alert('Nothing');
}
});
}
});
</script>
```

For hej.php:-

```
<?php


$one=$_GET['number'];
if(empty($one)) {
    echo "Can't be blank";
    $a['result']='null';
    $a['error'] = 'No value!!';
} else {
    if(is_numeric($one)) {
        $show=$one*2;
        $arr = array(
        'show'=>$show
        );
        header('Content-Type:application/json');
        echo json_encode($arr);
        exit();
       // echo $show;
    } else {
        echo "NaN";
        $a['result']='null';
        $a['error']='nan';
    }



}
?>
```

Comment: You can try  JSON.stringify(array) to encode your array in JavaScript, and then use $array=json_decode($_POST['jsondata']); in your PHP script to retrieve it. see this if it's usefull.

Comment: yes use JSON.stringify inside script in forsok.php and use $array=json_decode in your hej.php and let me know if its working.

Answer (score 1):

First create an array of what should be the output. JSON encode that array and then you can parse the output in your ajax success handler. Like in your php file output like:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'result' => 'null',
    'error' => 'nan'
));
```

Then in you ajax success turn the json into an object and parse data as you want:

```
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    $('#utmatning').html(obj.result); // result value from your json return
    $('#utmatning').append(obj.error); // error value from your json return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At last of your php file, add,

```
json_encode($a);
```

In ajax success,

```
success: function(html) {
    $.each(html, function(index, element) {
        alert(element.result);
        alert(element.error);
        //append to which ever div you want.
    });
}
```

Now with this, you can get `n` number of array indexes from php

Answer (score 1):

Instead of echoing strings here and there in in hej.php it might better to return JSON data to your ajax call. so you can evaluate if an error occured, which error it is or which valid result has been returned.

hej.php:

```
<?php
    $one=$_GET['value'];
    if(empty($one)) {
        $a['result']='null';
        $a['error'] = 'No value!!';
    } else {
        if(is_numeric($one)) {
            $a['result']=$one*2;
            $a['error']='ok';
        } else {
            $a['result']='null';
            $a['error']='nan';
        }
    }
    die(json_encode ($a));
?>
```

if $value was 1 that would return

```
{"result":"2","error":"ok"}
```

In forsok.php you could check the reults and act accordingly

```
...
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
    success: function(response)
    {
        if (response.error=='ok'){
            $('#utmatning').html(response.result); // show response from the php script.
        }
        else{
            console.log(response.result); // handle the error
        }
    }
});
...
```

Regards,
Stefan